# How to reset CapRover password?

Tags: server, caprover

I just installed CapRover on my server and I forgot my password ‍♂️
but I still have access via SSH normally.

How could I reset it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run these commands as [the documentation](https://caprover.com/docs/troubleshooting.html#reset-password) mentioned:

```
docker service scale captain-captain=0
```

### Backup config

```
cp /captain/data/config-captain.json /captain/data/config-captain.json.backup
```

### Delete old password

```
jq 'del(.hashedPassword)' /captain/data/config-captain.json > /captain/data/config-captain.json.new
cat /captain/data/config-captain.json.new > /captain/data/config-captain.json
rm /captain/data/config-captain.json.new
```

### Set a temporary password

```
docker service update --env-add DEFAULT_PASSWORD=captain42 captain-captain
docker service scale captain-captain=1
```